# Stop Halcon Camera in C#?

Tags: c#

I am using from Halcon (http://www.halcon.com/) and I convert it to C# and using in visual studio 2013 .
Now, I click on btnLive get me camera Live and when I click on btnLiveStop get me error . How I can Stop the camera ? I should use thread ? or ...

This is Live.cs :

```
using System;
using HalconDotNet;

public partial class LiveExport
{
  public HTuple hv_ExpDefaultWinHandle;
  Int32 Flag = 0;
  // Main procedure 
  public void actionLive()
  {

    // Local iconic variables 

    HObject ho_Image=null;


    // Local control variables 

    HTuple hv_AcqHandle = null;

    // Initialize local and output iconic variables 
    HOperatorSet.GenEmptyObj(out ho_Image);

    HOperatorSet.CloseAllFramegrabbers();
    //Image Acquisition 01: Code generated by Image Acquisition 01
    HOperatorSet.OpenFramegrabber("DirectShow", 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, "default", 8, "rgb", 
        -1, "false", "default", "[0] DFx 72BUC02", 0, -1, out hv_AcqHandle);
    HOperatorSet.GrabImageStart(hv_AcqHandle, -1);

    while ((int)(1) != Flag)
    {
      ho_Image.Dispose();
      HOperatorSet.GrabImageAsync(out ho_Image, hv_AcqHandle, -1);
      HOperatorSet.DispObj(ho_Image, hv_ExpDefaultWinHandle);
      //Image Acquisition 01: Do something
    }

    HOperatorSet.CloseFramegrabber(hv_AcqHandle);
    ho_Image.Dispose();

  }

  public void InitHalconLive()
  {
    // Default settings used in HDevelop 
    HOperatorSet.SetSystem("width", 512);
    HOperatorSet.SetSystem("height", 512);
  }

  public void RunHalconLive(HTuple Window)
  {
    hv_ExpDefaultWinHandle = Window;
    //actionLive();
  }

  public void StopStart(Int32 value) {
      this.Flag = value;
      actionLive();
  }
}
```

And in form.cs I Wrote these codes but when I click on btnStop don't work and show me No Responding (Please help me):

```
private void btnLive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HTuple WindowID = hWindowControl2.HalconID;
    LVDEV = new LiveExport();
    LVDEV.InitHalconLive();
    LVDEV.RunHalconLive(WindowID);
    LVDEV.actionLive();
}

private void btnLiveStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LiveExport LVDEVs = new LiveExport();
    LVDEVs.StopStart(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that need to be addressed here.  First, the way you "stop" an image grab is by calling the operator "SetFramegrabberParam" with "do_abort_grab":

```
private void StopAcquisition(HTuple hv_AcqHandle)
{
    HOperatorSet.SetFramegrabberParam(hv_AcqHandle, "do_abort_grab",1);
}
```

This operation corresponds to the `StartImageGrab` operation.

That said, to do this, you need several more changes to the architecture.  Unless you explicitly need to connect and disconnect from your camera, you should only call `OpenFrameGrabber` once and persist the variable `hv_acqHandle`, as well as pull out the `CloseFramegrabber` operator.

Then, the start and stop should make calls to a different while loop in another thread:

```
private CancellationTokenSource StartAcquire(HTuple hv_acqHandle)
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Task.Run(()=>{
        while(!tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
           ho_Image.Dispose();
           HOperatorSet.GrabImageAsync(out ho_Image, hv_AcqHandle, -1);
           HOperatorSet.DispObj(ho_Image, hv_ExpDefaultWinHandle);
        }, tokenSource.Token);
    return tokenSource;
}

public void StopContinuousAcquisition(HTuple hv_acqHandle, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
{
    if (tokenSource== null)
        return;
    tokenSource.Cancel();
    HOperatorSet.SetFramegrabberParam(_frameGrabber, "do_abort_grab", 1);
}
```

The reason your form is locking up is because your `while(true)` loop will not allow any events to register.  You must use a multithreaded approach in this case.